# Is there a way to fetch the first entry of a table in database using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table which stores names of people, i want to fetch the first entry of my database table. Is it possible using SQL query?

Comment: What do you mena by first entry  The row at the top of table or the row with minimum value of primary key?

Comment: first entry in the sense whoseever name i have entered first in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM names LIMIT 1
```

And if you want the first *sorted* entry, then use the following:

```
SELECT n.* FROM names n ORDER BY n.last_name ASC, n.first_name ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Naturally I'm assuming a whole lot about the schema of the table and the nature of the question. On the other hand, I'm 60% psychic, so just go with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`select first(column_name) from table_name order by primary_id`
first().is an aggregate function available for mssql
you can also go for 'top' in mssql

Comment: Ahem, this IS labeled as a MySQL question.

Comment: so you can use order by primary key limit 1