# How to fetch only a value from MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to fetch the first entry of a table in database using SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547440/is-there-a-way-to-fetch-the-first-entry-of-a-table-in-database-using-sql-query)

So, I downloaded a script(top-site script), i think that it's build up on the famous aardvark top site script.
Anyways my main concern is:

Lets take xtremetop100's one category, for ex : http://xtremetop100.com/call-of-duty . As you can see on the right side the category's name appears in h3.

**Call Of Duty top list**

*Skins, Maps, Sprays, and More*

My site's pretty much like xtremetop's, but when I click on different categories, the same title shows up, as if I'd visit xtremetop100's website, and when i click on another category , the title would be the same and ONLY ONE on each and every category.(hope you understand)

Now, I tried fetching the row, but I really didn't get the hang of it, as you can see, xtremetop100's page doesn't end with .php or .html, etc.

When I click on my webpage on a category it's like this:

```
?index&category=number_here(ex : ?index&category=19).
```

I really don't know how to make this happen, so that it analyses the link, and if it has the x ID , then it would select the exact category name with the same id. I have an sql table with 2 fields : ***id***, ***name*** . This is how i tried :

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("database");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM top_categories");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo " <b>name</b> = " .$row["name"] . ""; 
}

?>
```

This gives me all the categories from that table. I would like that when i click on the Call Of Duty category, it'll show a **Call Of Duty** title on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM top_categories
WHERE top_categories.id = your_id  
ORDER BY name ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but if I write a number in place of ***your_id*** then the category ( your_id = 1 ) title will appear on every other category. I mean the same category title will appear everywhere. What can I do so that every category page has it's category title?

Comment: @bobzrz8: Well, you need to supply a different ID for each category. In other words, don't hard-code your_id, but concatenate the number in it. To prevent possible SQL-injection, try to parametrize it.